# Openpyxl returning seemingly random value from cell with data validation, not the selected data

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am working on a project that is using a excel bid as a data source,

Our bid has a column for each row with a data validation drop down for staus of that aspect of the project,  Stuff like "Pre-Bid", "Bidding", "Not Bidding" "Awarded" etc.

I am trying to pull data from my bid based on the status,  The code works provided the cell is hard coded without the data validation drop down, but if there is a drop down in the excel sheet, then a seemingly random value from the drop down is returned.

Here is the code snipped that I am having problems with.

```
if verbose_mode.lower() == "y":
            for cell in QC_breakdown['B']:
                if cell.value == "Bidding":
                    #print(cell)
                    print(str(cell.offset(row = 0, column = 2))+ "  ", end="")
                    print(str(cell.offset(row = 0, column = 5)))
                    out_file.write(str(cell.offset(row = 0, column = 2).value)+ "  ")
                    out_file.write(str(cell.offset(row = 0, column = 5).value))
                    out_file.write("\n")
            out_file.write("\n")
```

I have tried opening the excel file in "data_only=True" mode.  This does not effect the results.

Comment: I'm assuming there are data validation lists for each row in column B. each with the source being text "Pre-Bid, Bidding, Not Bidding, Awarded"? Are you saying that if 'Bidding' is selected in one of the lists that the line if **cell.value == "Bidding":** fails and **cell.value** is equal to one of the other source values? This is not dynamic so the selection(s) is made and the workbook saved before the code is run?

Comment: Yes, each cell in column B does have a data validation list with those entries.  The Excel file is saved and not open, but when calling cell.value it will return Bidding, Pre Bidding, Not Bidding, Awarded, Etc.  Double-checking the excel spreadsheet shows that the cell is rarely correct.

Comment: OK. I have created a test sheet with 20 rows, and cols A, D and G with some random data and B with data validation as indicated. Not that I'd have expected different; running your code a number of times when various cells in col B have 'Bidding' selected, correctly displays the rows on which it is set. I cannot think of reason for you issue or that anything in the code sample would be the reason.

Comment: Interesting, might be something with the excel file then.  At least my code isn't terrible.  Thanks for your help!